# Unable to remove MySQL Table column

Tags: mysql

When I run the command I get following error:

**Command**

```
ALTER TABLE couuntries DROP IsDeleted



Error on rename of './db/#sql-812a_8' to './db/countries' (errno: 150)
```

The table has a column which is FK and constraint to other table

Comment: when you run what command...

Comment: @sfletche Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE couuntries DROP COLUMN IsDeleted
```

Comment: I had to remove FK field first. Still I am accepting it. Thanks